# Prevent entity from being created, but need entity for native query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have a native query that executes a stored procedure and the results is mapped to an entity, this works fine but the thing is the entity is created in the database (I'm referring to the actual table being created, but this table will always be empty), any way to prevent this?

I'm using JPA with hibernate and Sql Server 2005

Thanks

Comment: hibernate only creates a record when you tell it to, you must be doing something else as well

Comment: Hmmm it might be auto-discovery of JPA that creates the entities automatically, I'll try to disable it.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I just re-read your comment again, do you mean "record" as in database row? I'm talking about the physical table in the database.

Comment: So you are asking how the tables in your database get created ?

Comment: Not exactly how but preventing some of them being created. (So they can only be used to map the results from a native query) JB Nizet answered something I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an entity if it's not supposed to be stored in any database table. The query should return a list of objects which are instances of a class not annotated with `@Entity`.

That being said, letting hibernate generate the database schema for you is something you should only do for quick prototyping, at the very beginning of a project. Later, the schema should not be created automatically anymore.

Comment: So I can let hibernate map the results to class without @Entity? In this case there will be no associations. I agree about the auto-creation though

Comment: I've tried mapping it to class without @Entity, but I get a Unknown Entity exception.

Comment: Just query for the fields of the class, and build instances of the class yourself.

Comment: went the manual way, I'll have to join some tables and it will be a nightmare.